# Note Reading Newbie Issue for piano

Tags: piano, sheet-music, sight-reading

I'm new to piano and I'm working with Michael Aaron's Grade 1 piano book. I have question with respect to the following "Note Reading Tests":

[image]

Why is it that in the exercise above, they identify the note as an "Fa" but in the following they identify it as well as a "La". I'm guessing it might be a printing error since in the english label, they maintain "A" for both?

[image]

Comment: Looks like the author or editor was thinking treble clef instead of bass clef.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - that looks like an answer! Also note (sic) it's *fixed do*.

Answer (score 6):

Well spotted, as you say, this looks like a printing error. The note in the circle is "La" (A).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a misprint.  They happen!